# Tortoise Git not using id_rsa

Tags: windows-10, bash, ssh, git

I use Tortoise Git on Windows 10. When I push it asks me password although I do have `%userprofile%\.ssh\id_rsa` file. I also tried to use git from command line (Git bash). If I google I get instructed to write `IdentityFile` into `%userprofile%\.ssh\config`. I already have it there but it is still not working. I opened Process Monitor by Sysinternals and logged git.exe file system activity I found out that it does not even try to access anything in `.ssh` directory.
How can I make git to use this id_rsa file?

Comment: Does this help? https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key

Comment: Nope. If I understand correctly the solution is to have .ssh directory in your home directory and then id_rsa file in .ssh directory. I already have it. But seems like git.exe does not even try to access this file.

Comment: That's not at all what the answers there say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution!

The problem was that I was using https authentication instead of ssh authentication. This is why it never even tried to access key file.

The solution was to change it to ssh authentication:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.site.com:something/something.git
```

To verify that it is now ssh authentication instead I used `git remote -v`:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@gitlab.site.com:something/something.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.site.com:something/something.git (push)
```

And now they key finally worked.

PS: one final thing to keep in mind is that ppk keys don't work with git bash on windows. I learned it when I used `ssh -v -T git@gitlab.site.com` to verify that it accessing the correct key (Alternatively you can also use `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git pull` if you are currently in your git diretory). This command ended with saying: `error in libcrypto`.
To solve this I had to convert the key to open-ssh format. For that I used puttygen GUI but for those who want more explanation or command line then here is explanation: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/ssh-key-types-convert-ppk

I hope this response might be useful for someone.